# How to convert CSVRecord to List?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I need to convert a `CSVRecord` to a `List` to get the position of an element.

So I used this :

```
List<CSVRecord> records = csvParser.getRecords();
int i = records.get(0).indexOf(element);
```

However, `records.get(0)` returns a `List<CSVRecord>` and not a `List<String>`...

Moreover I cannot use `csvParser.getHeaderNames();` because after that I need to copy the file with the header.

Comment: What kind of `List` do expect to get by calling `records.get(0)`?

Comment: @TA why not an `Array List` or even an `Array` converted in `List` with `Arrays.asList`

Comment: so you want an `ArrayList<CSVRecord>`? I still dont quite get your problem.

Comment: I tried to answer this but realized I didn't understand your question properly, so what you want is not the value but only the index for a column? Or do you want to find a value?

Comment: If I have the value I can have the index. My main problem is conversion between CSVRecord and List.

Comment: You want to convert the CSVRecord to a List of what? `List<String>`?

Comment: Ok, I have undeleted my answer.

Comment: @TA list of `String` yes sorry.

Comment: @Royce dw, you should propably add that to your question though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the below function that I found on [geeksforgeeks.com](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-an-iterator-to-a-list-in-java/)

```
public static <T> List<T> getListFromIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) { 
    Iterable<T> iterable = () -> iterator; 

    return StreamSupport 
              .stream(iterable.spliterator(), false) 
              .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

and the fact that you can get an iterator from `CVSRecords` you can do

```
List<String> list = getListFromIterator(records.get(0).iterator());
```

Comment: This solutions seems to solve my problem. Thanks a lot. I have to check if this solution is not too much slow with a lot of data.